# Not convertible to UInt8

Tags: swift

```
if timerRunning == false {
    timerLabel = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timerRunning = true
    timerlabel.text = NSString(format: "%i",timerLabel) 
    if (timerlabel > topscore1lbl) {
        topscore1lbl = timerlabel
        topscore1lbl.text = NSString(format: "%i",topscore1lbl)
    }
}
```

I need help with this coding, I get

> 'UILabel' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

next to the `if` function

Comment: 1) `if` is not really a function. 2) Which `if`?  3) Holy cow... that was annoying to edit.  4) `!timerRunning` rather than `timerRunning == false`, *please*, and 5) no, just four... I don't have five points.

Comment: Okay, I've got a 5) ... you have a variable called `timerLabel` and another called `timerlabel`... **WHY???**

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @nhgrif. That code is a hopeless mess. There's more that's wrong with it than is right.

Your variable names make no sense whatsoever.

You have a variable name called `timerlabel` that appears to be a UILabel. Is that right?

Why do you have another variable called timerLabel that holds an NSTimer? It's a timer, not a label. And it's ludicrous to have 2 different variables with the same letters in the name but different case on a single letter holding totally different types of objects.

Why are you trying to convert timerLabel (the NSTimer) into an integer? You can't. It won't work.

What type is `topscore1lbl`? The name implies that it's a label, but your variable naming is all over the place, so we have no way of telling what it is.

If timer label is a UILabel, why are you trying to compare it to something else (topscore1lbl) using the ">" operator? Comparing a label to something with ">" makes no sense. It wouldn't make sense to compare the other variable timerLabel (the NSTimer) with the ">" operator either. This line is probably the one that's generating your error, but I have no idea what you're trying to do, so I don't know what to suggest to fix it.

Then what is the point of this line?

```
topscore1lbl.text = NSString(format: "%i",topscore1lbl)
```

You're setting something's text to it's integer value? Huh?

Can you edit your post give us a definition of each variable, it's type, and what it's used for, along with adding comments to each line of your code to tell us what you think each line is doing? Then we might be able to help you.

Based on the mess you've posted I'd say you are in way over your head. You should probably do a lot more reading, start with "hello world", and then work up slowly.

Comment: i am new to this and this is my first app so i just needed help.

Comment: As I said in my answer, it's pretty clear that you are over your head. Your code is riddled with mistakes that don't really make sense. I suggest you step back and do some more reading before you start trying to write original programs from scratch. Maybe read the Apple iBook "The Swift Programming Language" and/or go through the Stanford Swift programming video series?

Comment: I don't intend to be mean. You are likely to be very frustrated without a better understanding of what you're doing. Your current coding style is like opening the hood of a car and randomly adding auto parts and moving wires and hoses around in the hope of adding new features to your car's engine. The near-certain outcome of that approach is failure - sometimes spectacular, exploding failure

Comment: Can you help me with my other question I am trying to do the timer with ivar ?